# The formula for calculating work transfer for a reversible adiabatic compression

Tags: thermodynamics, work

Should we not be using Pdv for calculating the work done during a reversible  adiabatic process ? Why are we using Vdp ? Can some one please explain this ? (P.S. I'm taking an introductory course on Thermodynamics , so please keep it simple )

(Edit: The process in question is a steady state process. Does this fact change the work transfer formula ?)

Comment: Can you give more information on your process?

Comment: I'm sorry,but I've provided all the information I have .

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Derivation_of_P-V_relation_for_adiabatic_heating_and_cooling).